# How to fill an Arc on an Arc other?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Currently, I have two Arcs but there are small borders of the wrong color (see black arrow) :
xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing">
<Grid Width="150" Height="150">
    <ed:Arc
                                        x:Name="BorderArc"
                                        ArcThickness="15"
                                        StrokeThickness="0"
                                        ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel"
                                        StartAngle="270"
                                        EndAngle="45"
                                        Fill="Red"
                                        Stretch="None"
                                        RenderTransformOrigin=".5 .5"
                                        Width="150"
                                        Height="150">
    </ed:Arc>
    <ed:Arc
                                        x:Name="Border"
                                        ArcThickness="15"
                                        StrokeThickness="0"
                                        ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel"
                                        StartAngle="270"
                                        EndAngle="30"
                                        Fill="Gray"
                                        Stretch="None"
                                        RenderTransformOrigin=".5 .5"
                                        Width="150"
                                        Height="150">
    </ed:Arc>
</Grid>
```

[image]
Please give me a solution for remove small red border (see black arrow)? Thanks for help me?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the ArcThickness of the grey arc to 15.1, and see if that removes the red outline.

What happens if you give both arcs a white border of a single pixel?

### Option 1: Modify the ViewModel

Could your ViewModel be modified to process the Arcs like this:

```
ArcViewModels = new List<SingleArcViewModel>();

for (var i = 0; i < Arcs.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        ArcViewModels.Add(new SingleArcViewModel(Arcs[i].StartAngle, Arcs[i].EndAngle));
    }
    else
    {
        ArcViewModels.Add(new SingleArcViewModel(Arcs[i - 1].EndAngle, Arcs[i].EndAngle));
    }
}
```

(I am assuming that the constructor takes StartAngle first, then EndAngle).
Where `Arcs` is your existing list of Arcs, and `ArcViewModels` is what you will bind your View to. It has the StartAngle of each arc set to the EndAngle of the previous one.

I've tried this in a simple application and it works OK, obviously you will have to make some modifications to your view model to process the arcs for binding to.

### Option 2: Run the Arcs collection through an IValueConverter

You'll need to create a Converter class like this:

```
public class ArcCollectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var arcsCollection = value as ArcViewModel[];
        if (arcsCollection == null)
            return value;

        var result = new List<ArcViewModel>();

        for (var i = 0; i < arcsCollection.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                result.Add(new SingleArcViewModel(arcsCollection[i].StartAngle, arcsCollection[i].EndAngle));
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(new SingleArcViewModel(arcsCollection[i - 1].EndAngle, arcsCollection[i].EndAngle));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then add the following to the references in your View:

```
xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:LocalExperiment.Models"
```

The resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <cc:ArcCollectionConverter x:Key="ArcCollectionConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And use the converter wherever you are binding to the arcs collection:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyArcs, Converter={StaticResource ArcCollectionConverter}}"></ItemsControl>
```

You may need to modify some of the types to get it to work with your ViewModel, but hopefully this will get you started.

Comment: thanks for reply, I try set the ArcThickness of the grey arc to 15.1 but that not not completely removes the red outline.

Comment: How is your arc being created? Is it databound to an object?

Comment: Yes, It is, it databound to an object which return StartAngle and EndAngle of Arcs

Comment: Is it a fixed set of arcs, or a dynamic list? Are you able to change the Start of one arc to the End of the other (this removes the 'bleed-through' effect)?

Comment: you can and you have to change start of one arc to the end of another. You can use Arc.Loaded event to do it, or you can use MultiBinding and there are other posibilities for sure as well

Comment: it is a dynamic list and I can not that set the End of one arc is the Start of the other

Comment: But can you extend your ViewModel and produce a separate list, with the desired start/ends?

Comment: Have any way that change in file xaml for fix that ?

Comment: You could run your Arcs collection through a converter?

Comment: what about binding just StartAngle and EndAngle trought converter?

Comment: Because you need two different objects in the same collection to bind to what is a dynamic array, probably rendering through templates. Could you make an example to show?

Answer (score 0):

You have one arc on top of another. just modify them to not overlap:

```
<!-- I have ommited some properties -->
<ed:Arc StartAngle="30" EndAngle="45" Fill="Red" />
<ed:Arc StartAngle="275" EndAngle="30" Fill="Grey" />
```

Comment: thanks for reply, My Arcs is a dynamic list and I can not that set the End of one arc is the Start  of the other

Comment: include code details in you question, how you actually get and show the dynamic list of Arcs.